# Image Browsing using Kohonen's SOM

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision, som

I am trying to create a visual browsing application for millions of images using Self-Organizing maps(SOM). Does anyone know of the existing image browsing systems that use Self Organizing maps(SOM) at the backend. I know that PicSOM uses SOMs. I would be curious to know others, so that I can learn from them, before I implement one.

Also what is the most trusted source of Kohonen's SOM algorithm C++ code? I think http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som1.html is pretty good. Does anyone know other trusted implementations of SOMs in C++?